# clean annoying characters in string

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

include_once("tester.php");  

$name = New noticion;

if ($name->datos("localhost","root","","tester")) {
echo "conexion abierta<br>";

$ver = $name->vereste("74","a");

echo "<pre>".stripslashes($ver[2])."</pre>";
echo "<br>";

$ver = $name->vereste("65","b");

echo "<pre>".stripslashes($ver[2])."</pre>";
echo "<br>";

}
```

In the first  I have a result with many \ "\" \ "and \" \ \ n n which resolve rapidly with stripslashes (). The issue is that I always use the same function for all the news. If I do that sack the \ n and turn them into something leaving n "n [+] Sintax: $ 0  n"; news that the second show in the same way. I can also not use htmlentities because I show HTML code. If I do labels disappear and ruins everything.
Use these codes to show news programming of various languages
How I can solve this torture?

Comment: ummm... what? what is an example of code you have stored, and how should it look to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a simple str_replace to keep the \n

I would do this:

```
$cleanthis = array('\ "\" \ "', '\" \\');
$cleaned = str_replace($cleanthis, '', $ver[2]);
echo $cleaned;
```

This should leave you with only \n or \n n I'm not sure that the second n is also a problem for you or type error. but its a problem for you than do a second str_replace like this:

```
$secondclean = str_replace('\n n', '\n', $cleaned);
echo $secondclean;
```

But it would be helpfull if you could provide a var_dump() from your data before the stripslashes()

Than maybe you could try this:

```
$a = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $ver[2]);
$a = str_replace('n n', '\n', $a);
echo $a;
```

Comment: yes , I try to str_replace () several times but never replace anything, same with your code I do not understand what happens

Comment: Added an edit to my answer, try it, maybe it will work for you.